# Add one month until it is greater than some value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have start date & Mdate  as columns in table, i want to do something like below in SQL

Add 1 month to Start_Date until  start date  > Mdate

I tried using while and if concepts,  but no luck.

```
DECLARE @MIGRATIONDATE DATE, @STRT_DATE DATE, @NEXTD DATE
SET @MIGRATIONDATE =20140725
SET @STRT_DATE = 20140521

SELECT WHILE ( @STRT_DATE > @MIGRATIONDATE)
         BEGIN 
             DATEADD(MM,1,@STRT_DATE))
         END
```

appreciate if you can guide me on this?

Comment: Edit, please. Provide an example schema and the queries you have tried with it and not working. Perhaps you may be committing a minor mistake in those queries which is causing you the issues. If not, it will help us analyse your problem better. Please add details.

Comment: In a stored procedure or in a plain SQL query?

Comment: iN A PLAINE sql QUERY PLS?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you would like to get one row of that table. If you want to do it for each row, then you should wrap it in a function and use CROSS APPLY.

```
declare
@startdate datetime, 
@enddate datetime

set @startdate = '20140101'
set @enddate = '20150101'

;WITH date_range (thedate) AS (  
  select @startdate  
  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, thedate)  
            FROM date_range  
            WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, thedate) <= @enddate  
            )  
SELECT  thedate FROM date_range
```

If you wanted in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExplodeDates](@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
returns table as
return (

WITH date_range (thedate) AS (  
  select @startdate  
  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, thedate)  
            FROM date_range  
            WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, thedate) <= @enddate  
            )  
SELECT  thedate FROM date_range   
);


SELECT Id,thedate
FROM   Table1 T1
       CROSS APPLY [dbo].[ExplodeDates](T1.StartDate,T1.EndDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
     case when start_date<Mdate then dateadd(mm,1,start_date) else start_date end
   from yourTable
```

suppose start_date is 20140721 and MigrationDate is 20140525 then it returns you with gives you accepted result

```
select case 
        when convert( date,'20140721') <convert(date,'20140525')
         then dateadd(mm,1,'20140721') else '20140721' end
```

Comment: it jumps on else part because in your table start_Date is not greater than MIGRATIONDATE.

Comment: Yeap, sorry. I am trying to achive where it should keep adding until start _date is less than mdate. For ex. if my startdate = 20140102 and mdate is 20140720, i want add month to start date untill it becomes 20140602. In this scenario, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30fdd/5/0)):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 
               DATEDIFF(month, Start_Date, Mdate) + 1, 
               Start_Date) AS NEW_START_DATE
FROM MyTable;
```

If there is a possibility of the Start_Date being greater than or equal to Mdate then use the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e24d9/3/0)):

```
SELECT Start_Date AS OLD_START_DATE,
      CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, Start_Date, Mdate) > 0 
      THEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, Start_Date, Mdate) + 1, Start_Date)
      ELSE Start_Date END  AS NEW_START_DATE,
      Mdate
FROM MyTable;
```